# Core can't be identified in uVision, but commander works fine

Tags: keil, segger-jlink

We're working on a FPGA Dev enviorment with a Cortex M33.

We have JlinkPro, JLink Lites.

Can connect to the Core with Jlink Commander no issues, although in uVision the core doesn't come up in the device chain.

Sometimes if you start GDB Server, Keil somehow finds something in the device chain and asks you to select the core type and then works. But this does not always work with all software version of uVision.

Has anyone had any similar experiences or work arounds?

Tried Different Versions, trying to keep a connection enabled etc

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

Keil uVision was keeping around a stale JlinkSettings.ini and the Core was set to ARMv7!

Changed it to M33 and off it went!